# MongoDB simple bulk insertion should be faster than 1000 inserts/second

Tags: node.js, mongodb, caching, mongodb-query

I need to show an an undefined amount of `$group`s from a collection of thousands of documents, say 5000, based on user input. For this, my main query has 4 `$lookup`s. Even with indexes on the `foreignKey`, this still takes about 2 seconds.

That in itself surprises me a bit. 5000 * 4 indexed lookups, should that really take 2 seconds? But that's not the biggest issue.

On the first request, the collection needs to be generated from live data, based on user input. Rendering and inserting these documents takes about 10 seconds. It's complex, so that's normal.

This means that the first request takes 12 seconds, and every follow up request takes 2 seconds.

In order to expedite those follow-up requests, it seemed like a good idea to do all the `$lookup`s once, and save this as a new cache collection. Querying from this prepared cache only takes about 0.1 seconds.

I assumed that would mean the first request now takes 12 seconds (I do need to wait for the write (`{w:1}`) because now the grouping selects depend on the cache being generated), and the rest take 0.1 second.

The problem is that I hugely underestimated the time it takes to write out the documents to the cache. First I just inserted the aggregated array into a new collection. I optimized that using a bulk operation. I shaved off another second by using streams:

```
let bulk        = db.cache.initializeUnorderedBulkOp()
let cursor      = db.data.aggregate(pipeline)
let stream      = cursor.stream()
stream.on('data', document => bulk.insert(document))
stream.once('end', () => Promise.resolve(bulk.execute({w: 1})) // Data needs to be there before I can query it in the next step.
```

This action makes the 2 second query take about 10 seconds to complete. Is that normal for ~5000 documents? It's only about 15 MB of data. (So I guess the stream is a good thing. I'm close to the 16 MB query limit.)

Now the initial request takes 22 seconds. and the rest 0.1. That is not the optimization I had in mind.

Is there a way I can circumvent or better tackle this problem?
Is there a faster way to return knowing writes are done, without receiving 5000 insertion `_id`s in a `writeOpresult`?
Should using `$out` be significantly faster?

- MongoDB 3.2
- WiredTiger

#### Inline update

I was able to use a fast 8 core Intel i7 with 16 GB RAM. The insertion of 4000 documents takes "only" 4 seconds. This is still insane. On internet, I read articles ranging from 20.000 inserts/second to 100.000 inserts/second. What I have here, is 1000 inserts/second.

### MongoDB log

As you can see in the mongo log itself, the query that is fed to the bulk insert operation really does take less than 2 seconds:

> **db.data command: aggregate**
>       { aggregate: "data", pipeline: "[...]", cursor: { batchSize: 1000 } }
>       cursorid:155377253006 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:10 reslen:3953728
>       **locks**:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 8034 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 4017 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 4017 } } }
>       protocol:op_query **398ms**
>   **db.data command: getMore**
>       { getMore: 155377253006, collection: "data", batchSize: 1000 }
>       planSummary: PIPELINE_PROXY cursorid:155377253006 keysExamined:0  docsExamined:0 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:8 nreturned:1000 reslen:4000968
>       **locks**:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 8036 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 4018 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 4018 } } }
>       protocol:op_query **393ms**
>   **db.data command: getMore**
>       { getMore: 155377253006, collection: "data", batchSize: 1000 }
>       planSummary: PIPELINE_PROXY cursorid:155377253006 keysExamined:0 docsExamined:0 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:8 nreturned:1000 reslen:3906423
>       **locks**:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 8028 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 4014 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 4014 } } }
>       protocol:op_query **501ms**
>   db.data command: **getMore**
>       { getMore: 155377253006, collection: "data", batchSize: 1000 }
>       planSummary: PIPELINE_PROXY cursorid:155377253006 keysExamined:0 docsExamined:0 cursorExhausted:1 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:8 nreturned:972 reslen:3938471
>       **locks**:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 7796 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 3898 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 3898 } } }
>       protocol:op_query **388ms**

**Total: 1680ms**

### Initial `$lookup` pipeline

This pipeline does the initial lookups for the cache. Included by request.

```
[
    {
        "$match": {
            "meta.string": "some string"
        }
    }, 
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0, 
            "meta": 1, 
            "attributes": 1, 
            "relationships": 1, 
            "type": 1,
            "id": 1
        }
    }, 
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "as": "lookup01", 
            "foreignField": "id", 
            "from": "data.lookup01", 
            "localField": "relationships.lookup01.id"
        }
    }, 
    {
        "$unwind": "$lookup01"
    }, 
    {
        "$redact": {   // This specific id is often but 
            "$cond": [ // not always unique. meta.string is.
                {
                    "$eq": [
                        "$lookup01.meta.string", 
                        "some string"
                    ]
                }, 
                "$$KEEP", 
                "$$PRUNE"
            ]
        }
    }, 
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0, 
            "meta": 1, 
            "attributes": 1, 
            "relationships": 1, 
            "type": 1,
            "id": 1, 
            "lookup01": "$lookup01.attributes"
        }
    }, 
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "as": "lookup02", 
            "foreignField": "id", 
            "from": "data.lookup02", 
            "localField": "relationships.lookup02.id"
        }
    }, 
    {
        "$unwind": "$lookup02"
    }, 
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0, 
            "meta": 1, 
            "attributes": 1, 
            "relationships": 1, 
            "type": 1,
            "id": 1, 
            "lookup01": 1, 
            "lookup02": "$lookup02.attributes"
        }
    }, 
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "as": "lookup03", 
            "foreignField": "id", 
            "from": "data.lookup03", 
            "localField": "relationships.lookup03.id"
        }
    }, 
    {
        "$unwind": "$lookup03"
    }, 
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0, 
            "meta": 1, 
            "attributes": 1, 
            "relationships": 1, 
            "type": 1,
            "id": 1, 
            "lookup01": 1 
            "lookup02": 1, 
            "lookup03": "$lookup03.attributes"
        }
    }, 
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "as": "lookup04", 
            "foreignField": "id", 
            "from": "data.lookup04", 
            "localField": "relationships.lookup04.id"
        }
    }, 
    {
        "$unwind": "$lookup04"
    }, 
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0, 
            "meta": 1, 
            "attributes": 1, 
            "relationships": 1, 
            "type": 1,
            "id": 1, 
            "lookup01": 1, 
            "lookup02": 1, 
            "lookup03": 1, 
            "lookup04": "$lookup04.attributes"
        }
    }
]
```

### Resulting example cache document

Unfortunately, the documents comprise both public and proprietary data, and I am not allowed to post actual data here. This is an impression of the kind of documents that are inserted in cache. Basically, it is (was) JSON-API structured data, with the relationships included.

```
    "_id" : ObjectId(),
    "type" : "data",
    "id" : 123,
    "meta" : {
        "date" : ISODate(),
        "date2" : ISODate(),
        "string" : "",
        "number" : 123
    },
    "attributes" : {
        "partnerData" : {
            "boolean" : true,
            "string01" : "",
            "string02" : "",
            "string03" : "",
            "string04" : "",
            "string05" : "",
            "number01" : 123,
            "number02" : 123,
            "number03" : 123,
            "number04" : 123,
            "subdocument" : {
                "array01" : [ 
                    {
                        "number" : 123,
                        "string" : ""
                    }
                ],
                "array02" : [ 
                    {
                        "number" : 123,
                        "string" : ""
                    },
                    {
                        "number" : 123,
                        "string" : ""
                    }
                ],
                "array03" : [ 
                    {
                        "number" : 123,
                        "string" : ""
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "number01" : 123,
        "number02" : 123,
        "number03" : 123,
        "number04" : 123,
        "number05" : 123,
        "number06" : 123,
        "number07" : 123,
        "boolean01" : false,
        "boolean02" : false,
        "boolean03" : false,
        "boolean04" : false,
        "boolean05" : false
        "boolean06" : true,
        "string01" : "",
        "string02" : "",
        "object01" : null,
        "object02" : null,
    },
    "relationships" : {
        "lookup01" : {
            "id" : 123,
            "type" : ""
        },
        "lookup02" : {
            "id" : 123,
            "type" : ""
        },
        "lookup03" : {
            "id" : 123,
            "type" : ""
        },
        "lookup04" : {
            "id" : 123,
            "type" : ""
        },
        "array01" : [ 
            {
                "id" : 123,
                "type" : ""
            },
            {
                "id" : 123,
                "type" : ""
            }
        ],
        "array02" : [ 
            {
                "id" : 123,
                "type" : ""
            },
            {
                "id" : 123,
                "type" : ""
            }
        ]
    },
    "lookup01" : {
        "number01" : 123,
        "number02" : 123,
        "boolean05" : false
        "boolean06" : true,
        "string01" : "",
        "string02" : "",
        "string03" : "",
        "string04" : "",
        "string05" : "",
        "string06" : "",
        "string07" : "",
        "object01" : null,
        "object02" : null,
    },
    "lookup02" : {
        "number01" : 123,
        "number02" : 123,
        "boolean05" : false
        "boolean06" : true,
        "string01" : "",
        "string02" : "",
        "string03" : "",
        "string04" : "",
        "string05" : "",
        "string06" : "",
        "string07" : "",
        "object01" : {
            "number" : 123,
            "string" : ""
        },
        "object02" : {
            "number" : 123,
            "string" : ""
        },
        "object03" : {
            "number" : 123,
            "string" : ""
        },
        "object04" : {
            "number" : 123,
            "string" : ""
        }
    },
    "lookup03" : {
        "string01" : "",
        "string02" : "",
        "object01" : {
            "number" : 123,
            "string" : ""
        }
    },
    "lookup04" : {
        "number01" : 123,
        "number02" : 123,
        "number03" : 123,
        "number04" : 123,
        "number05" : 123,
        "number06" : 123,
        "number07" : 123,
        "boolean01" : false,
        "boolean02" : false,
        "boolean03" : false,
        "boolean04" : false,
        "boolean05" : false
        "boolean06" : true,
        "string01" : "",
        "string02" : "",
        "string03" : "",
        "string04" : "",
        "string05" : "",
        "string06" : "",
        "string07" : "",
        "object01" : {
            "number" : 123,
            "string" : ""
        }
    },
    "date03" : ISODate()
}
```

### Indexes

Indexes for each collection are on `meta.string` and the lookup collections `data.lookup0x.id`

- `_id_` (default)
- `id_1`
- `meta.string_1`

Comment: Those numbers seem ridiculously high. But in order to help you we will need sample documents, the queries your are trying to run and information about indexes/other potentially relevant configuration.

Comment: @dnickless I cannot provide all the data, but I've added some mockup.

Comment: What's the [explain](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#return-information-on-aggregation-pipeline-operation) ouput for your query?